# Возможно ли передать потомка вместо родителя в функцию?

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

Есть класс и класс потомок:

```
class A{
  public:
    A(){ i = 5; };
    void do(){ cout << "do" << "\n"; };
  private:
    int i;
};

class B : A{
  public:
    int getI(){ return i; };
    void do(){ cout << "do from b" << "\n"; };
};
```

Возможно ли передать потомка вместо родителя в функцию?

```
void function(A a);
...
B b;
function(b);
```

Как? На такой вариант компилятор ругается:

> ошибка: «A» является недостижимой базой «B»

**UPD**

Мне также нужно, чтобы при вызове метода `do()` из функции `function`:

```
void function(A a){
  A.do();
}
```

вызывался метод `B::do()`, а не `A::do()`.

Comment: Используйте публичное наследование `class B : public A{`
Но вообще этого не делать не следует потому что в общем случае происходит object slicing. Используйте  указатели или ссылки

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало.

Comment: @zenden2k, перенесите комментарий в ответ, пусть вопрос не болтается не отвеченным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы вызывался метод потомка, а не родителя, метод Do() надо объявить виртуальным. Также надо использовать указатели на объекты, чтобы механизм виртуальных функций работал. (если метод объявлен виртуальным, то вызывается его реализация в наследнике, если таковой нет - родительский вариант)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    void virtual Do()
    {
        cout << "do" << "\n";
    };
};

class B : public A{
public:
    void Do()
    {
        cout << "do from b" << "\n";
    };
};

void func(A* a)
{
    a->Do();
}

int main()
{
    B* b = new B();
    func(b);

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: @reload пожалуйста

Comment: Для того чтобы механизм виртуальных функций работал, помимо указателей можно использовать ссылки (что удобней, так как сложней нечаянно передать nullptr).

Answer (score 3):

Используйте публичное наследование `class B : public A{` Но вообще этого не делать не следует потому что в общем случае происходит object slicing. Используйте указатели или ссылки

Comment: Простите, забыл кое-что. Смотрите update.

Comment: @zenden2k: Мне кажется, стоит написать пару слов про object slicing, будет полезно для данного вопроса. Без этого непонятно, откуда взялось требование передавать по указателю.